# Prove that $\int_{a}^{b} h(x)dx = \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{k} h(x^{k}_{j})\frac{b-a}{k}$ using given intermediate points.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, alternative-proof

**CONDITIONS**

- $h : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.
- For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $x^{k}_{1},...,x^{k}_{k}\space$ be points in $\mathbb{R}$ such that for each $j\leq k$ we have

$$a+\frac{(j-1)(b-a)}{k} \leq x^{k}_{j} < a + \frac{j(b-a)}{k}.$$
Note that the $k$ represents an index and not a power.

Indeed the proof itself can be done with the Fundamental Theory of Calculus Proof but that's with end points given. How can this be proven through the points given above?

Comment: What is your definition of the Riemann integral?

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{\Delta x_{k}\to 0} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x_{k})\Delta x_{k}.$ But what does have to do with this particular question?

Comment: Can you relate this definition to the thing you want to prove? They look similar but are slightly different; you may need to use the continuity of $h$.

Comment: Well obviously I know it uses continuity but I want the proof. If I knew I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: I am trying to guide you to find the answer yourself by hinting that you should think about how the right-hand side looks like the limit of a Riemann sum, which could potentially relate to the definition of the Riemann integral $\int_a^b h(x) \, dx$. If you have honestly thought about this and still cannot fill in the details, then maybe someone else can help you out.